# Mysql update joins?

Tags: mysql

Currently I am updating my different tables like so

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE boardposts SET lastPosterID = ?, postOrder = NOW() WHERE postID = ?");
$q -> execute(array($user['id'], $_GET['view']));
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET msgBoardPosts = msgBoardPosts+1 WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
```

Is it possible to put these kinda update in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It is possible, Something like:

```
UPDATE    boardposts AS bs 
left join accounts   AS a on bs.AccountId = bs.lastPosterId
set bs.lastPosterId = ?, bs.postOrder = NOW(),
    a.msgBoardPosts = msBoardPosts + 1
WHERE bs.postId = ?,
      a.id = ?
```

I didn't now the structure of your two tables but this is the basic idea see the syntax of [`UPdate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference SET....
>   The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this I have been using 2 queries and sometimes even 3, looks like I got some coding to do!